# jQuery DataTable on done search event?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to call certain function when user search the datatable, including when they erase all the text inside search input (all the data shown).

I have the code like below:

`$(tbl).on('order.dt search.dt',function() { urutkan_no(tbl); });`

It successfully fired when user fill something in search input, however when they erase all the text, the event won't fired anymore.

Is there any DataTable event which is triggered when user emptying the search input (after the whole data shown)? or is there any workaround to do this?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that now I know better what happened. This is my example code for my problem. Please try this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
});
var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','cyan','orange','limegreen','pink'];

$('#example').on('order.dt search.dt',function() {
    console.log('search', $('.dataTables_filter input').val());
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $('#example tbody').find('tr').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('background-color',random_color);
        $(this).find('td:first').text(1+i);
    });
});
```

the function is called too early when the datatable is still not done drawing.

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a1z4533s/

Comment: I assume "order.dt" and "search.dt" are events. So why not calling `on` function once for each event?

Comment: @derloopkat yep they're 2 different datatable's events, but the have same callback, so I write it in one line.

Comment: the rules of this website say you need to publish minimum code for reproducing the problem.

Comment: `search.dt` is fired on *every* filter action, also when the user clears the search input.

Comment: @davidkonrad If that's true, I won't ask this question. My function is called/trigerred when I fill the search input, but when I clear it, all data in the table are indeed showing back, but my callback function not called.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/966/

Comment: @davidkonrad this is ridiculous. that example is working seamlessly but this code wont: `$('#example').on('order.dt search.dt',function() { 
 $('#example tbody').find('tr').each(function(i) { $(this).find('td:first').text(1+i); });
});`

Comment: I've updated my question above

Comment: @Tauf have you edited your question to post the solution?  ...if so, that's not how you resolve a question here.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this example in the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/event/preDraw#Example) what you need is`draw.dt` event:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var startTime;
table
.on( 'preDraw', function () {
   startTime = new Date().getTime();
} )
.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    console.log( 'Redraw took at: '+(new Date().getTime()-startTime)+'mS' );
} );
```

Edit: I just realised that this event is also fired after reorder and probably this is not what you want. But for my case it was harmless.